# FastApi href URL

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

Im struggling with populating a href tag in a HTML file with Fast Api and Jinja2.
The local context of the server is being prepended to the URL within the path of the link.

I have a SQLite db with a couple of columns, one of which is a string containing a URL

| ID | URL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | www.google.com |

I am passing that to a HTML template with Jinja2 tags as such
`<a href="{{ qr.link }}" target="_blank" class="ui blue button">{{ qr.link }}</a>`

The resulting page shows the link text correctly, i.e. "www.google.com", but the linked URL is the local app path with the intended URL added to the end, i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/www.google.com

Adding "url_for()" to the Jinja2 tag results in an error
`<a href="{{ url_for(qr.link) }}" target="_blank" class="ui blue button">{{ qr.link }}</a>`
starlette.routing.NoMatchFound: No route exists for name "www.google.com" and params ""

Im sure this is super simple, but I have not been able to find an answer anywhere here or elsewhere.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to add a protocol identifier in front of your link if it's not part of your database - i.e. `https://` or `http://`. `url_for` is for generating a link to internal routes. You're just linking to a file named `www.google.com` on your own server if you don't have any protocol identifier in front.